# MDC-Web: Multiple dialogs

Tags: javascript

I use google MATERIAL COMPONENTS FOR THE WEB and have problems with the "Dialogs".

Check my codepen: [Dialog](https://codepen.io/QJan84/pen/xYYPOR)

What do I have to do to have multiple dialogs per page?

**JS:**

```
// Find all the dialogs on the page
const dialogEls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-dialog'));

dialogEls.forEach((ele) => {
  const dialog = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(ele);

  dialog.listen('MDCDialog:accept', function() {
    console.log('accepted');
  })

  dialog.listen('MDCDialog:cancel', function() {
    console.log('canceled');
  })

  // From here I do not know how to continue....
  // Here the selector '#dialog-login' should still be dynamic
  document.querySelector('#dialog-login').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    event.preventDefault(evt);
    dialog.lastFocusedTarget = evt.target;
    // This shows all dialogs, which is wrong.
    dialog.show();
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dialog opens twice because you create two event listeners for #dialog-login.
One of them opens the Login Dialog the other one opens the Delivery Dialog.

Since you have two different distinct Dialogs, I would suggest a more static way and declare both dialogs independently:

```js
const dialogLoginEle = document.getElementById('mdc-dialog-login');
const dialogLogin = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(dialogLoginEle);
dialogLogin.listen('MDCDialog:accept', function() {
  console.log('accepted login');
});
dialogLogin.listen('MDCDialog:cancel', function() {
  console.log('canceled login');
});

const dialogDeliveryEle = document.getElementById('mdc-dialog-delivery-condition');
const dialogDelivery = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(dialogDeliveryEle);
dialogDelivery.listen('MDCDialog:accept', function() {
  console.log('accepted delivery');
});
dialogDelivery.listen('MDCDialog:cancel', function() {
  console.log('canceled delivery');
});

document.querySelector('#dialog-login').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  dialogLogin.show();
});
document.querySelector('#dialog-delivery').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  dialogDelivery.show();
});
```

https://codepen.io/j-o-d-o/pen/XZqNYy?editors=1010

---

Here a "dynamic" approach as requested, but IMHO this is not very readable and error prone.

```js
// Find all the dialogs on the page
const dialogEls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-dialog'));
// First one is the Login, Second one is the Delivery
var dialogArr = [];
dialogEls.forEach((ele) => {
  const dialog = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(ele);
  dialog.listen('MDCDialog:accept', function() {
    console.log('accepted');
  })
  dialog.listen('MDCDialog:cancel', function() {
    console.log('canceled');
  })
  dialogArr.push(dialog);
});

document.querySelector('#dialog-login').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  dialogArr[0].show();
});
document.querySelector('#dialog-delivery').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  dialogArr[1].show();
});
```

https://codepen.io/j-o-d-o/pen/jZxmxa?editors=1010

Comment: A good approach! But it would not be so difficult to make your code dynamic? Similar to my approach? I do not want to have to work in js afterwards.

Comment: I think it makes zero sense to have any "dynamic" approach in this case. Of course, you can create the element array and save the Dialogs in an Array and then use these in the eventHandlers for each button. But imagine you change, the position of the Dialog in HTML, you would have to remember to also change the index in javascript... not nice imho.

Answer (score 3):

I have updated answer from [@Jodo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48900908/2583709).
I suggest for dynamic approach using data attribute on dialog tags with value of opening button.

```
// Find all the dialogs on the page
const dialogEls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-dialog'));

dialogEls.forEach((ele) => {
  const dialog = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(ele);
  dialog.listen('MDCDialog:accept', function() {
    console.log('accepted');
  })
  dialog.listen('MDCDialog:cancel', function() {
    console.log('canceled');
  })
  document.querySelector('#' + ele.dataset.dialog).addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    dialog.show();
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/woytam/pen/abvdZBQ?editors=1010

Simply add `data-dialog` attribute to each dialog with value of your button/link. JavaScript function then will use `ele.dataset.dialog` in foreach.